# $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user null on 404 page

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, global

Why the user object is null on 404 pages ? The 404 page is set by `pageNotFound_handling`. Only on this page the user object is null .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because TYPO3 requests the page in the background, without any session cookies set, so when rendering the 404 page, noone is logged in. TYPO3 then sends the result from that request to the client.

It can't send session cookies or something, since you could set any page in `pageNotFound_handling`, not just pages on the same domain.

I have no idea how to fix/circumvent it, but I'm interested in a solution too (especially since I use the same thing for 403 pages and more).

Comment: I found this on forge https://forge.typo3.org/issues/76627 .. Hope that this helps, yet i didn't tried to patched anything. I will come back with conclusion :)

Comment: They said that the 404 page is handled by the server and it's not possible to send sessions, cookies on this